# Identifying a capacitor specs from its labels supposedly "10T16" or "10T1G"

Tags: capacitor, identification

[image: Photo of the capacitor with the label "10T16" or "10T1G"]

Anyone have any idea what the "G" is? And a cross reference for a replacement?

Comment: What G? All I see is 10T16, which could be 10µF tantalum at 16V.

Comment: By the picture it looks like a 6 but in hand it is a G

Comment: And the 0 is actually []?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a G, it's a 6 (in the same way that the 0 looks like () - it's how they are printed, using a silk screen process which requires bits of the masking to be fixed together, (like those army stencils pained on the side of boxes you see in cheesy 16's army movies).

The first number, `10` (or `1()`) is the capacitance in microfarads (10µF).

The second number, `16` (or `1G`), is the voltage rating - 16V.

The "T" in the middle could be a date code (Vishay use T for 2005), a tolerance, a package type, or just the fact that it's tantalum. You'd have to find the exact part and get the datasheet to decode that letter.

The actual device is a tantalum polarised capacitor, the ++ marking which is the positive pin.

Comment: That's what I needed to know. I searched and found a 10 16v tantalum. I just hope it didn't fry anything else. It was a oversight on my part on a kiln controller. The heater wire was touching the metal box and it shorted back through the main pc board through the temperature reading thermocouple.

Comment: I'll bet it made a nice bang. I have only had the misfortune to blow up one tantalum in my time - a 10V one with 12V across it. Bits of the casing embedded in the housing it was in...  Nice.

Comment: Nope not a single noise. The only way I knew was I had a error code come up and it coded to open circuit thermocouple. Pulled it open and check the connections and seen the top of the capacitor blown off.

Comment: Guess seeing as how I ran 120v through a 16v capacitor it didn't have much time to do much but melt down.

Comment: Yeah, instant fried capacitor brains. Nom nom nom.

Comment: Thanks for your help. At least I'm one step closer to getting this thing back online.

Comment: Not to be a negative Nancy, but connecting 120V to a thermocouple input will normally be expected to fry other stuff.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany You can be Nancy if I can be Frank. Yes, you should look for more signs of escaped Magic Smoke™.

Comment: But I might have gotten lucky and it popped the capacitor before other damage was caused. Nothing else looks burned. So unless it got to the Integrated Circuits it should be fine.